# On rhel8 os When I run a program the kernel crash, how can I determine which line of code reports the error ？

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, filesystems, redhat, xfs

I don't know about kernel, I don't know how to troubleshoot.

When the problem happened, my system kernel crashed, the following is the vmcore-dmesg.txt log
##dmesg logs

```
[  378.442884] SPDMD-LUN:[ERROR]lun_del:2218 device nvfile-mgmtd-0 is busy :2
[  424.511211] XFS (nvfile-storage-0): Mounting V5 Filesystem
[  424.513045] XFS (nvfile-storage-2): Mounting V5 Filesystem
[  424.538953] XFS (nvfile-storage-2): Starting recovery (logdev: internal)
[  424.546536] XFS (nvfile-storage-2): Ending recovery (logdev: internal)
[  425.512217] XFS (nvfile-storage-0): Starting recovery (logdev: internal)
[  425.518929] XFS (nvfile-storage-1): Mounting V5 Filesystem
[  425.520813] XFS (nvfile-storage-3): Mounting V5 Filesystem
[  426.288987] XFS (nvfile-storage-3): Starting recovery (logdev: internal)
[  426.475465] XFS (nvfile-storage-1): Starting recovery (logdev: internal)
[  427.496551] XFS (nvfile-storage-0): Ending recovery (logdev: internal)
[  428.320932] XFS (nvfile-storage-3): Ending recovery (logdev: internal)
[  428.977479] XFS (nvfile-storage-1): Ending recovery (logdev: internal)
[  445.927118] BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 0000000000000008
[  445.927685] PGD 0 P4D 0
[  445.928216] Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP NOPTI
[  445.928723] CPU: 4 PID: 591 Comm: kworker/u193:1 Kdump: loaded Tainted: G           OE    --------- -  - 4.18.0-305.el8.x86_64 #1
[  445.929735] Hardware name: Lenovo ThinkSystem SR860 V2/7Z60CTO1WW, BIOS M5E118K-1.52 08/06/2021
[  445.930305] Workqueue: xfs-cil/nvfile-storage- xlog_cil_push_work [xfs]
[  445.930910] RIP: 0010:blk_queue_split+0x1c6/0x660
[  445.933048] Code: c0 45 31 f6 89 44 24 44 89 7c 24 40 31 ff 85 db 0f 84 56 04 00 00 8b 44 24 44 48 89 c1 48 89 44 24 30 48 c1 e1 04 49 03 4d 78 <8b> 41 08 8b 71 0c 48 8b 11 44 29 f8 39 d8 48 89 54 24 48 0f 47 c3
[  445.936323] RSP: 0018:ffffbcbf9a4bfaf8 EFLAGS: 00010246
[  445.936711] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000003000 RCX: 0000000000000000
[  445.937028] RDX: 0000000000000018 RSI: 0000000000000018 RDI: 0000000000000000
[  445.937343] RBP: ffffbcbf9a4bfb90 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: ffff940c1965d700
[  445.937659] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffff94ca6f590000
[  445.937979] R13: ffff940bda0ddc80 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000000
[  445.938304] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff940effd00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Kernel problems are usually related to hardware drivers. If the kernel error message appears to be the nvme file system, it is recommended to consult the host manufacturer to confirm the system version (kernel) that the host can use.